# Why is Python running slow after heavy code?

Tags: python, performance, operating-system, environment-variables, environment

I am running a short but heavy code - it involves for example

```
v = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
A = np.meshgrid(v, v, v, v, v, v, v, v, v, v)
```

where A happens to have 6^10 elements, and it is used to carry out some calculations.

The code runs correctly in the console (takes around 1 minute), outputs what it should, but after that everything becomes incredibly slow. Like, in the next input even `2+2` takes around 20 seconds to be computed.

The weird fact is: even if I delete all the variables and restart the Kernel, the problem is not solved. I have to reboot my computer.

Comment: "kernel"? if you are using jupyter it is important to explicitly mention it

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for you comment: I am using Jupyter (on Win and Linux). It should be 3.9.7 on both (I ran "python_version()")

Comment: You've run out of memory and your OS has used some swap?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille how can I check that?

Comment: On Linux you can check that with top. On Windows with the process manager.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Sorry, I don't understand. I am relatively new to coding: what should I keep an eye on?

Comment: This has nothing to do with coding. It is just basic computer software tools to monitor your machine (see [this](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/htop-command-in-linux) and [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/task-manager) which are the first link I got on a basic search engine -- this does not require any special knowledge).

Comment: @JérômeRichard well, I thought I had to look at something specifically. While the heavy cell is running, CPU and Memory go up to 99%. But after everything gets back to normal. But still, 2+2 takes 20 seconds to compute.

Comment: ... just noticed that after the "2+2", memory and CPU went wild for a while again (but apparently, AFTER outputting "4").

Comment: Well a 99% memory use means this is certainly the swap (see the additional information in the tools). Swapping is slow because it use storage devices. You need to reduce the memory usage (possibly the ones of started applications). That being said `A` should take only about 500 MiB.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Shouldn't it get back to normal after the cell runs and after I've deleted all the variables, though?

Comment: I mean, it does, but it is still extremely slow...